# JMeter - way to have separate lines in graph based on text in the response

Tags: text, graph, jmeter

I am using JMeter to send a small load via a load balancer to a backend system that has three servers.

All requests sent are the same.  The backend servers merely returns response text that has info about that server, such as server name the request ran in.

I am doing this to demonstrate how load balancing works, to show load is spread fairly evenly over the backend servers.

What I'd like to be able to do with JMeter, is show three lines in a single graph, one line for each server, to in effect show requests going to the different servers.

I've googled on this for quite some time, but cannot find any way to do this in JMeter.

I've looked at assertions, and while I can get an assertion to find specific text in the response, and in the assertion listener, I can see the result of that, that's a text output display, and I'd really like a graph.

Is there some way I can configure JMeter so that it would produce a graph with a line for each backend server ?

Logically what I want to be able to do in JMeter is:

- for each response
  if response has text with string "Server-A"
  then label this response as "Server-A"
  if response has text with string "Server-B"
  then label this response as "Server-B"
  if response has text with string "Server-C"
  then label this response as "Server-C"
- graph with three lines - one for Server-A, one for Server-B, one for Server-C

Answer (score 0):

Just change your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label to the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding your "server" name which can be extracted from the response using suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and JMeter will display it in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) (or you can use any chart like [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) - this guy you can install using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

[image]